# Why I can't get keyboard input in this C# program?

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm trying to develop a simple UDP chat.

The problem in this code is that keyboard input is not getted!
Why ?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class UDPClient
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Use: {0} <listenport> <sendport> <dest_ip>", Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        int portno, portno_dest;
        if (!int.TryParse(args[0], out portno))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Porta di ascolto non valida");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        string dest_ip = args[2];
        IPAddress dest_addr;
        if (!IPAddress.TryParse(dest_ip, out dest_addr))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Indirizzo IP non valido");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        if (!int.TryParse(args[1], out portno_dest))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Porta di invio non valida");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        UdpClient client = new UdpClient(portno);
        IPEndPoint remoteEp = new IPEndPoint(dest_addr, portno_dest);
        Console.WriteLine("Socket created");

        Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate {
            // 
            client.Close();
            Environment.Exit(1);
        };


        while (true)
        {
            // msg received 
            byte[] receivedBytes = client.Receive(ref remoteEp);
            string receivedMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes);
            if (receivedMsg != "")
                Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", receivedMsg);

            // send message
            Console.Write("Insert message: ");
            string msg = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            client.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, remoteEp);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent message: {0}", msg);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Consider switching to TCP, UDP is meant for realtime apps where it **doesn't matter if some packets are lost**. For chat apps, TCP is better because **all packets are guaranteed to be received in order**

Comment: `UdpClient.receive` waits for a message, blocking the app so that nothing else runs until one arrives. The structure of the `while` loop suggests that it's probably waiting for a message, preventing the cancel handler from being triggered.

Answer (score 1):

`client.Receive(ref remoteEp);` is a blocking method, so you won't be able to send messages until a message is received. In order to fix it, you can use threads - one thread for sending messages, and another one for receiving.

In addition, as [Samarth Pradeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18071273/samarth-pradeep) mentioned, you should use TCP for chat app, rather than UDP (Regardless of the usage of threads).